# How to calculate expectation value of exponentiation of number operator for coherent state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coherent-states, thermal-field-theory

I consider a quantum harmonic oscillator and regard $a$ and $a^\dagger$ is ladder operators. Let $|0\rangle$ be a vacuum, and a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ is defined as the eigenstate of the annihilation operator;
$$a|\alpha\rangle=\alpha|\alpha\rangle,$$
$$|\alpha\rangle=\exp{(\alpha a^†-\alpha^*a)}|0\rangle$$
Then how can I calculate the following expression?
$$\langle\alpha|\exp N|\alpha\rangle=?$$
where $N=a^†a$.

Comment: latex tip: use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >

Comment: are you familiar with the representation of the coherent state as a sum of eigenstates of $N$? (it can be directly derived from the definitions you gave of $|\alpha\rangle$)

Comment: have you tried expanding $\exp N$ as a series and trying to compute $\langle \alpha|(a^\dagger a)^n|\alpha \rangle$ for $n\in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in following way:
Expansion of $|\alpha \rangle $ in $|n\rangle$ given by 
$$|\alpha \rangle=\langle0|\alpha\rangle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n !}}|n\rangle$$
where $$\langle0|\alpha\rangle=exp(-\frac{1}{2}|\alpha|^2)=r(say)$$
Now
$$e^N|\alpha \rangle=r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n !}}e^N|n\rangle=r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n !}}e^n|n\rangle$$
Thus
$$\langle\alpha|e^N|\alpha\rangle=rr^*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n\alpha^{*n}}{n!}e^n$$